# Android release build crashes when opening ARScene

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm getting the below issue when I try to open an ARScene in Android release build. I am not using the 'onTrackingUpdated' method at all.

```
 2019-08-05 11:27:29.851 15376-15376/? E/Viro: ERROR: [/Users/manish/workspace/ViroRenderer/android/app/../../ViroRenderer/VROPlatformUtil.h: VROPlatformCallHostFunction(), line 300]
ERROR: Unable to find method onTrackingUpdated callback.
2019-08-05 11:27:29.852 15376-15376/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp.sample, PID: 15376
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lcom/viro/core/ARScene;.onTrackingUpdated(II)V"
at com.viro.core.internal.PlatformUtil.runTask(Native Method)
at com.viro.core.internal.PlatformUtil.access$000(PlatformUtil.java:58)
at com.viro.core.internal.PlatformUtil$TaskRunnable.run(PlatformUtil.java:78)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

In Debug build it works fine and I'm able to load a 3D model successfully. The issue happens only in Android Release build.

Comment: Look for progaurd-rules need to be applied during release, for libraries you have used.

Comment: Removing progaurd solved my issue